# I am trying to output a query from a sqlite database to a list, but I am not getting correct results

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper

```cs
public static List<StudentModel> LoadPointCounts()
{
    using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
    {
        var output = cnn.Query<StudentModel>("SELECT PointCount FROM Student");
        return output.ToList();
    }
}
```

My values for each index in the list are just "ClassroomRaffle.StudentModel" when it should be a numeric value. Anything that jumps out to you guys here?

EDIT: Those who asked, here is the StudentModel

```
public class StudentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PointCount { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how I am displaying the data from the list. (not completed yet, I plan on adding a loop to go through each value)

```
pointcounts = LoadPointCounts();
label.Text = pointcounts[0].ToString();
```

Comment: `cnn.Query<int/decimal/etc>` but why then are you returning a List<StudentModel>?

Comment: Your query is written `cnn.Query<StudentModel>`, so the results are stored in `StudentModel` instances.  When you look at the list in the debugger (which I'm assuming you are doing), the debugger is calling `StudentModel.ToString()` on each instance to display what is there.  Your `StudentModel` class (which you don't show) likely doesn't override `ToString()`, so you get the base `object.ToString()` which simply shows the name of the class

Comment: For what it's worth, (since you are new here) you could make this question much better by doing a few things: 1) show the `StudentModel` class, 2) Show at least part of the `Student` table definition (the whole thing would be great, but we really need the definition of the `PointCount` column),  3) describe how you are observing the *values for each index in the list*

Comment: Sorry, if I am not quite detailed enough.I will edit the post to include more info.

Comment: So my comment above is what is happening.  Your query is returning a list of integers, each named `PointCount` because of the column name.  But, you are telling Dapper `cnn.Query<StudentModel>`, which means "return the data as a `List<StudenModel>`", so Dapper creates a `StudentModel` for each entry returned, and uses the `PointCount` data to initialize each entry (the `Id` and `Name` properties will get set to their defaults (0 and null)).  You want to change your query to `cnn.Query<int>` (as @stuartd suggested).  By the way, that's a *much* better question

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for and getting back a `List` of `StudentModel`, not a list of integers.

If you just want the ints, something like:

```
public static List<int> LoadPointCounts()
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {
            var output = cnn.Query<int>("SELECT PointCount FROM Student");
            return output.Select(i => i).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't you mean `cnn.Query<int>`? Well, I can tell from the next statement that you don't. But I see no reason to query for StudentModels, if all you want are integers.